# Using variables in class types

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused by how all this should work. I'm trying to create an object which can have unlimited fields all having different/dynamic types (so I don't know in advance which types they are).

I have a first class `ConditionParamField<T>`, and I think this one is kind of ok. It represents the key:value that will be stored in a file

```java
public class ConditionParamField<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;

    public ConditionParamField(String name, T value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I then have `ConditionRule`. It extends the `Rule` from the jeasy package. The main idea is just to have a map of key:type which will tell what keys are needed and what their type should be. My idea would be that the `<?>` here will be filled in where `T` is in the class before (`ConditionParamField<T>`)

```java
public interface ConditionRule extends Rule {
    /**
     * Request values that need to be filled in by the user
     */
    HashMap<String, Class<?>> getNeededValues();
}
```

These 2 come together in a simple manager class. My idea would be to map over the needed fields and create my `ConditionParamField` instances:

```java
ArrayList<ConditionParamField<?>> conditionParamFields = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Class<?>> neededValues = conditionRule.getNeededValues();

            for (String field : neededValues.keySet()) {
                Class<?> clazz = neededValues.get(field).getClass();
                ConditionParamField<clazz> conditionParamField = new ConditionParamField<>(field, null);
            }
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I'm not very familiar with Generics or whatever <?> is called.
I hope you understand what I try to achieve.

The main issue here is that I get an error "Class clazz unknown" for `ConditionParamField<clazz>`. It seems like he doesn't take the variable, or maybe that's not possible at all to do, I'm not sure.

My final main goal will be to show the user an input that will only accept whatever type the field was (Integer, String,...)

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking here? What's the problem?

Comment: I get an "Unknown clazz class" error from my IDE for `ConditionParamField<clazz>`

Comment: You cannot use a variable / value as a generic type parameter.  The Java syntax requires a type at that point ... not an instance of `Class`.

Comment: @StephenC I figured that out yes, but what could be the solution here then?

Comment: Change `ConditionParamField<clazz>` to `ConditionParamField<?>` ... I think.  There is not enough (code) context to be sure.

Comment: @StephenC That would work but that means that `ConditionParamField` won't have a type. Maybe I'm trying to do something in a very incorrect way. The main idea would be to just have a black-box POJO with unlimited keys/values, but the key:type structure is defined. What code context would be missing?

Comment: @StephenC Here is the part in the actual code if that could help: https://github.com/titivermeesch/CommandTimer/blob/f074430ea1b89a9e9ce9cc77fc3ff5ee3be06665/src/main/java/me/playbosswar/com/gui/validations/SimpleConditionMenu.java#L68